# The HTML Doctype is automatically changing from XHTML 1.2 to XHTML 1.0

Tags: html, doctype, cpanel

On a html page the doctype I've used is as follows (for a mobile website):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" 
"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
```

which after uploading on the web server automatically turns into

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

To make it clear this change happens as soon as I save the page on the server. (using cPanel)
Any idea on what could be the reason for this (automatic) change? 
Because of this the layout of the page is not coming out as I expect it to be on some browsers.

Comment: Have you tried not using cPanel?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no such thing as XHTML 1.2

Comment: @Gordon — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML_Mobile_Profile

Comment: There is indeed a XHTML Mobile 1.2, though it was superseded by XHTML Basic 1.1.

Comment: @Jeremy: I'm not sure how to try that without using cPanel. I'm working remotely so I just edit the page through cPanel. Is it possible to access the page without cPanel? Sorry I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Is it a doctype problem server problem or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have SSH access to your server? If so, try logging in and looking at the file you uploaded. If you can, edit the doctype with vim, emacs, or nano, and see if it works. If so, then it is probably cPanel changing it for you.

Comment: @Jeremy: looks like your suggestion helped me, I've mentioned it as an answer below. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out the exact problem, it happens only when I use the cPanel editor to edit the html page and not when I just upload the file and not open it in their editor. As Jeremy said in the comments below the question, it's cPanel changing (screwing?) it for me!

Thanks a lot everyone, especially Jeremy! :)

btw should I now delete this question or keep it as someone else might also face similar issue?

Comment: I imagine cPanel has, and will, change (screw up) other people's files in the future. I say keep it around.